Which scan topic should be used by slam toolbox in localization mode?
I use ROS1 Noetic.
I have mapped an area using slam toolbox in mapping mode and using the data from /scan1.
Is it necessary to use the same scan topic later in localization mode, or can I use a different /scan2?
Thank you

Do you mean; can you run your localization node with /scan2 topic on your map which is created with /scan1 topic? If so, the answer is yes. You can use different scan topic.
